# Style Echo in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I used this code to echo value from custom field on my WooCommerce Shop.
But now i have problem with styleing this text - how can I do that?

```
    // Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

    global $woocommerce, $post;

    // Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
        array(
        'id'          => '_textarea',
        'label'       => __( 'My Textarea', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' )
    )
    );
}
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

    // Textarea
    $woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['_textarea'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_textarea ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', esc_html( $woocommerce_textarea ) );

}
```

Comment: i return value of field by this code : echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_textarea', true );

Comment: Problem is , i cant  select this element, i tryed to wrap it inside html tags, but it have no effect

Comment: How did you try to wrapoit?

Comment: Exacly how you post in answer - also another method to wrap entire <?php ?> inside div or p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`woocommerce_wp_textarea_input` accepts style and class parameters.

```
woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
        array(
        'id'          => '_textarea',
        'label'       => __( 'My Textarea', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'class' => 'special-class'
    )
    );
```

Then the item should be wrapped in the `special-class` class and you can use CSS to style it any way you like.

```
.special-class {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic. You have to echo the html. Add a class to that html and then style it using CSS.

```
echo '<p style="color:blue;">'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_textarea', true ).'</p>';
```

Comment: Problem is, i tried already to make it like this - not worked, its why im asking for help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
            array(
            'id'          => '_textarea',
            'label'       => __( 'My Textarea', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder' => '',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'class' => 'special-class'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
   $woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['_textarea'];
   if (!empty($woocommerce_textarea)) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_textarea', esc_html($woocommerce_textarea));
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );


function demo(){
    global $product;
    $meta = get_post_meta($product->id, "_textarea", true);
    ?><p class="custom-text"><?php echo  substr($meta, 0, 300); ?> </p><?php 
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','demo');
```

I have displayed stored value for particular product.
i have used **Demo** namely funcntion to display value on product page.